# How can I remove a Gmail account in macOS?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

I have a Gmail account that has a conflict, how do I remove my Gmail account from my Mac Air?

Comment: Remove the account in Sytem Preferences : accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Is it from the Mail App?
Go to Mail>Preferences>accounts
then click on your gmail then the minus ( - ) button to remove it.